# PostgreSQL, try to get a exclusive lock using FOR UPDATE, and if not, try getting shared lock FOR SHARE

Tags: postgresql

I'm attempting to gracefully ask for an exclusive lock using `FOR UPDATE`, but in the case that some other thread already holds an exclusive lock, then attempt to acquire a shared lock `FOR SHARE`.

What's the correct way of doing this in PostgreSQL or in SQL in general? Perhaps it's just a matter of putting the `NO WAIT` with the first attempt, and then handle the error?

See: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE

Comment: `NOWAIT` and a retry loop would be your only option with PostgreSQL really. Of course, when you fail the exclusive lock and try a share lock instead, someone else might have just released an exclusive lock so you take a share lock when you could've acquired an exclusive lock. This will tend to result in low rates of successful exclusive locking and excessive share locks.

Comment: That's precisely what I want, I want most of my threads to hold a shared lock.